# how to use cakephp dompdf for a print all function

Tags: cakephp, dompdf

I'm already using dompdf to generate a pdf for each single view of my project using view_pdf function explained in cake tutorial

```
public function view_pdf($id = null) {
  $this->Stock->id = $id;
  if (!$this->Stock->exists()) {
    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid stock'));
  }
  // increase memory limit in PHP
  ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
  $this->set('stock', $this->Stock->read(null, $id));
}
```

Now I need to have a "print all" button which have to make a pdf file contain whole views.
Could I use view_pdf function in a "for each" loop? And could I make a file for this specific pdf instead a view?

I'm quite new on CakePhp so it's very appreciated a code example.

Thanks !!!

Comment: You would want to use a single `view_pdf` method. Loop through all the views and append them to the same HTML document. Then render the final output to PDF when that's done. Maybe something like `$this->set('stocks', $this->Stock->find('all')` and a loop in your view to display each stock.

Comment: Also, which tutorial? And could you clarify your last paragraph. E.g. by "whole views" do you mean all the records? What do you mean by "make a file" instead of a view?

Comment: thanks BrianS for your suggestion i followed this link tutorial http://deliciouscakephp.com/how-to-generate-pdf-in-cakephp-2-x-with-dompdf/

Comment: This example is making a view , user  could download or print  the html page produced on the screen . Since i need to print all records produced by performing a search (they could be few or a lot i'm not able to know in advance) it's not useful  them displayed, this is why i'm asking for make a file running this procedure in silent mode for the user.

Comment: Ah, so you need something done in the background. It's a bit more difficult, but still doable from within the CakePHP environment. You'd have to run the render in a separate process. You could spin one up from an interactive session or use a cron job to run any queued jobs. I have some sample code for running Cake offline, but I'll have to find it.